# Google Blogger API : Fetch Blog Posts securely

Tags: api, google-api, blogger

I'm really new to Google API's, so bear with me. I am trying to fetch posts from my blog. Blog is set as **private**.

Problem lies here:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
    "message": "The calling IP address x does not match the IP restrictions configured on the API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions.",
    "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials?project=x"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The calling IP address x does not match the IP restrictions configured on the API key. Please use the API Console to update your key restrictions."
 }
}
```

I got an google account where I have Blog, project in Google API Console and API key for it. I tried changing API key restriction to HTTP but same problem occurs, thou error message is slightly different.

[image]
[image]

Fetching works like this:

```
var apikey = "x";
var blogId = "x";

  $(function(){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url:"https://www.googleapis.com/blogger/v3/blogs/"+blogId+"/posts?key="+apikey,
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  });
```

I double checked all variables and they are correct. API key is correct one, and so is BlogId.

With this stew console is giving me 403 error. I hope I'm being clear enough. Ill be fixing this post when answer is found :)

Answer (score 1):

API key is used to access public data.  Public data is data that is not owned by a user personally.  Videos uploaded to YouTube as public for example.

Your blogger data is private user data.  You are going to need to use Oauth2 to access it.   Once you have authenticated using oauth2 you will need to use access_token={tokenfrom auth} instead of using Key.

I am not sure why the IP address isn't working I haven't actually bothered with that before.

Comment: Okay, I did not know that! Thanks for that!

Comment: How should I proceed? I am trying to figure out how to access Google Blogger API using Oauth2.0, but I am stuck. I don't know what I should do. I've been reading documentation forever and it has not help to me.

Comment: I am not a ajax dev so I cant be of much help.   this might help you will have to alter it to use blogger once you get it working with people.  https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/samples/samples#authorizing-and-making-authorized-requests  javascript was the closest I can find.  once you have something kind of working post your code under a new question.